# When to set Index on created_at column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing

Do I need to add an index to `created_at` for a query like this?

```
User.posts.where('created_at > ?', 3.months.ago)
```

The posts table in general is quite big (hundreds of thousands of records), but every user has on average a couple of dozen posts and maximum around 100.

Are there some general rules you apply for setting indices in these types of cases?

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not the right query

```
User.posts.where('created_at > ?', 3.months.ago)
```

as this must be something like this

```
current_user.posts.where('created_at > ?', 3.months.ago)
```

also it is not mandatory to add index but for better performance you should add `index: true` to your migration of Post table with user reference.
Something like this

```
t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question I'm afraid.

Answer (score -4):

No, don't use indexing. use caching. I am not sure where you are making this call in your code so I can't give a more specific answer. But this guide will get you started in the right direction.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-store

I use Redis for this. This gem https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails has worked well for me.

Comment: The question isn't about how to create indexes but when one should do so.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understood your question. I will update my answer.

Comment: It wasn't my question, but anyway, why do you advocate not using indexes which is an absolute basic way of getting better performance?

Comment: If you cache the response you only run the query once, if use indexes you run the query every time the page loads. Over time caching is always faster than adding indexes. I did answer your questions it was "Do I need to add an index to created_at for a query like this?  ..." the answer is no it is a waste of your time and wont help the speed of your site as much as caching.

Comment: It is not my question, @Randomtheories is the op. Anyways, just because caching is valuable doesn't mean you should not use indexes to speed up the first time you do the query. Using indexes in the db doesn't mean you cannot use caching in Rails.

Comment: By making more columns indexes you slowing down inserted/deleted/updated and you use more RAM. If that isn't important to you why not index every column.